# Minecraft 1.17.1 Mod en_us.json file not working

Tags: java, json, eclipse, oop, minecraft

I have a problem with my json file ,I try to create an item named Ruby but the name in game is item.mymodid.ruby my code looks like this :

```
{

"item.mymodid.ruby": "Ruby"
```

}

I'm new to code and I don't understand what is wrong in this , thx for help

Comment: Where did you put this file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've placed the en_us.json file in the directory resources\assets\Your-Mod-ID (replace with your modid)\lang\en_us.json

Also, the information that you've provided is not enough. Mention your mod-id, create a git repo for concise information, and most importantly, post the log using pastebin or paste.ee or something.